# Need help building the best performing SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity

I'm making a Listener, so that I'll be able to post gamedata form multiple games to my server. I will use that to keep clients in sync, no matter what device they play on! This part I'm done with, Using Entity and Linq for inserts and loading playerdata when they are desync'ed.

Every webpost to the server takes about 2-10 ms, depending on the data beeing sent.
(which i hope is fine!). This is mostly FirstOrDefault selects, modyfing some data and SaveChanges.

But the server also has to feed the clients with Scoreboards. both "Today/All Time" and "Everyone/Friends only".

I tried with some Linq SQL queries. but when i look at the output I'm really scared of how its gonna preform (with hopfully thousands of users, and millions of score records).

**Here's an example:**

```
using (BertEntities BGE = new BertEntities())
{
    var query =
       (from score in BGE.ScoreTable
        join game in BGE.GameSession on score.GameSessionID equals game.ID
        join user in BGE.User on game.UserID equals user.ID
        where
                game.PublicHighScore == true &&
                game.Banned == false &&
                game.GameID == GameID &&
                score.LevelID == level
        orderby score.Score descending

        select new ScoreResult
        {
            ID = user.ID,
            Name = user.FacebookName,
            Score = score.Score,
            Streak = score.Streak,
            Time = score.Time
        }).Skip(skip).Take(count);


    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query.ToList());
}
```

**Which gets executed like this**

```
SELECT TOP (100)
    [Project1].[Score] AS [Score],
    [Project1].[ID] AS [ID],
    [Project1].[FacebookName] AS [FacebookName],
    [Project1].[Streak] AS [Streak],
    [Project1].[Time] AS [Time]
    FROM ( SELECT [Project1].[Score] AS [Score], [Project1].[Streak] AS [Streak], [Project1].[Time] AS [Time], [Project1].[ID] AS [ID], [Project1].[FacebookName] AS [FacebookName], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[Score] ASC) AS [row_number]
        FROM ( SELECT
        [Filter1].[Score] AS [Score],
        [Filter1].[Streak] AS [Streak],
        [Filter1].[Time] AS [Time],
        [Extent3].[ID] AS [ID],
        [Extent3].[FacebookName] AS [FacebookName]
        FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[LevelID] AS [LevelID], [Extent1].[Score] AS [Score], [Extent1].[Streak] AS [Streak], [Extent1].[Time] AS [Time], [Extent2].[UserID] AS [UserID], [Extent2].[GameID] AS [GameID]
            FROM  [dbo].[ScoreTable] AS [Extent1]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[GameSession] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[GameSessionID] = [Extent2].[ID]
            WHERE (1 = [Extent2].[PublicHighScore]) AND (0 = [Extent2].[Banned]) ) AS [Filter1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[User] AS [Extent3] ON [Filter1].[UserID] = [Extent3].[ID]
        WHERE ([Filter1].[GameID] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Filter1].[LevelID] = @p__linq__1)
    )  AS [Project1]
)  AS [Project1]
WHERE [Project1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Project1].[Score] DESC
```

I'm no SQL expert, but that looks pretty tough to me. (Taking into account that I want this to scale, even with millions of records and thousands of requests without killing the server.)

This is the database layout:
[www.invokergame.com/db.png](http://www.invokergame.com/db.png)

I'm thinking of storing all the data I need in the ScoreTable table, so I'd avoid making the joins. but that would result in a lot of duplicate data, and I'm pretty sure that's the wrong approach.

Maybe I should forget about Entity Linq, and write it in ADO.NET SQL (which I'd need help with)?

Sorry about the wall of text, I'm looking forward for some wise words!

**Edit:**

Okay TomTom, Is this what you ment by faking it? Dragging all the data I need into one dataset. And then use LINQ to update or remove and select items from this list, when a user makes a new highscore, or disable PublicHighScore?

And how will this perform?

```
public class ScoreCacheItem
{
    public Int64 ScoreTableID { get; set; }
    public Guid GameID { get; set; }
    public int LevelID { get; set; }
    public Int64 UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public int Streak { get; set; }
    public double Time { get; set; }
    public DateTime Today { get; set; }
    public int Today_Score { get; set; }
    public int Today_Streak { get; set; }
    public double Today_Time { get; set; }
}


public sealed class ScoreCacheSystem
{
    private List<ScoreCacheItem> FScoreCache = new List<ScoreCacheItem>();
    private object FLock = new object();

    private List<ScoreCacheItem> LoadAllScores()
    {
        using (BertEntities BGE = new BertEntities())
        {
            var query =
               (from score in BGE.ScoreTable
                join game in BGE.GameSession on score.GameSessionID equals game.ID
                join user in BGE.User on game.UserID equals user.ID
                where
                        game.PublicHighScore == true &&
                        game.Banned == false 
                orderby score.Score descending

                select new ScoreCacheItem
                {
                    ScoreTableID = score.ID,
                    GameID = game.GameID,
                    LevelID = score.LevelID,
                    UserID = user.ID,
                    Name = user.FacebookName,
                    Score = score.Score,
                    Streak = score.Streak,
                    Time = score.Time,
                    Today = score.Today,
                    Today_Score = score.Today_Score,
                    Today_Streak = score.Today_Streak,
                    Today_Time = score.Today_Time
                });
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }

    public List<ScoreCacheItem> HighScores {
        get
        {
            lock (FLock)
            {
                if (FScoreCache == null)
                {
                    FScoreCache = LoadAllScores();
                }
                return FScoreCache;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at your database design, I'm trying to determine whether you need the ScoreTable at all.  At first glance, the player's score can go in the GameSession table.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant do that. I only store 1 record pr gamesession / per level. but because of the "per level". every gamesession is gonna have multiple ScoreTable records. one pr. level :)

Comment: This shouldn't necessarily be a problem with the right indexes in place. Sql Server can create smart execution plans for queries that look complex, it also caches execution plans, and the amount of data sent over the wire is small. Try some stress tests first before optimizing something that maybe doesn't need fixing at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a serious problem in the SQL side. EF does quite good SQL - but here I would argue that the use of a SQL Server in general is bad.

If you need to have this type of query answered super fast, then do that from memory - not from a database server. In-memory lookups are typical for simple queries that are repetitive and time sensitive for data distribution (financial trading - no one would write prices into a database then have the client pull them; you distribute them while writing them to a store).

Otherwise you just can fake it - caching comes to my mind. There is not a lot you can do to optimize the requirement for a significant database server with this architecture. Make sure your indices are in place. Work from the query plans to make sure you do not miss anything.

But really, try to avoid hitting SQL Server at all - cache output at all levels. And the SQL is quite trivial, BTW. Things get interesting when you hit 2-3 screen long analysis queries ;) Millions of records are not the issue, the main issue will be concurrent requests. The connection better have read-committed isolation to make sure you do not set locks. And then get a proper server and scale out unless you change the architecture.

> Im thinking of storing all the data I need in the ScoreTable table, so
>   I'd avoid making the joins. but that would result in alot of duplicate
>   data, and im pretty sure thats the wrong approach.

Absolutely not - like not the wrong approach. Denormalization is typical in a read-heavy reporting database. You can use triggers to maintain this table automatically. Whether it makes sense in your situation must be tested with a good data set. It is not generally bad but standard practice in data warehousing, although those normally deal with real amounts of data (billions of rows, not something tiny like a million or two). In my last larger data warehousing project we were loading around 450 million rows a day - and had to archive them for 10 years for reporting. Look up "Star Schema" on Google. Rules are different for basically read only / data warehousing scenarios.

Comment: Hi TomTom, thanks for this great answer! However its confusing me abit, how Im gonna manage the data in the memory. With SQL I know where my data is. And I'll be able to easily backup the data.

Would it be the same if i used SQL Server 2014's new InMemory OLTP?
 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133186(v=sql.120).aspx
Or is there somewhere i can find some examples using the methods you are talking about? (Im guessing I'd also have to do this on all my Inserts?). Its not that i don't want to understand what you're writing, but I'm already pushing my ability, and this sounds complex :)

Comment: Can you check my Edit in the main post, and see if thats a proper method?

Comment: Well, I never ever use datasets and then ther are tons of caching APIÄs in .NET... You may also want to separate hot and cold data - having it all in memory is not smart, some data will just never show up normally (because it is too old).

Comment: Hmm, but the data really never gets to old, because it will only hold their current records, and since there's an "All Time" leaderboard. And I thourght of defining their "World Rank" by checking their index in the list. (is there anything dangerous about this?) I testet with a list of 40million records, and I as able to fetch the data i wanted in 0.4ms. (using LINQ on the list Where, skip, take etc.) There will be constant requests to the server, so Isnt this just like "always having the data in hand"?

Comment: Oh, it does. See, who cares about nr. 33 of the top list? NEARLY NOONE. Data does get old - as in: it is not going to be presend most of the time. Most people will look at the current top lists only.

Comment: Sorry i posted before i was finished writing :) But I also need the ability to do a Where(Friendlist.Contains(id)) .. and one of a persons friends might be rank 3.000.000 in the world. Actually the "Friend Leaderboards" is default in the client

Comment: Then start saving for hardware. Scale out as you need more servers. Not a problem - you just need to throw tons of REAL hardare at the issue if it gets larger. Real hardware like "No cheap vm but a real built database server".

Comment: That's not a problem, if it scales to 40.000.000 users, affording the hardware wouldn't be the problem. I just want to make sure that the method it viable.  I got this concern, i can't sort the list, cause that take way to long. so I have to insert a new score at the right position in the list. (this takes about 40ms). will this cause errors for the readers of the list? do i need to lock it, and what drawbacks would that give.

Comment: Abolutly viable. See, the changes will be miniscule compared to the data - so you look at a scale out scenario and can use replication or a DAG for that. One server manages the changes, X servers are hit by the applicaiton to do the reporting.

Comment: Okay :) I can't wrap my head around combining multiple servers! But if I setup a cloud server (that will scale to 120gb RAM and 32cpus) I guess that would last for a while. And then save the concerns for when I can't scale it any larger :) But as I said before, wouldn't I get errors on the reader threads, if they are called while the list is being modified by another thread?

Comment: Well, problem is that a SQL Server lives with IO, followed by RAM ;) And no - you would get locks and waiting. SQL Server is quite good at handling this - in fact, lock handling is a fundamental core functionality of a database. Just make sure your selects use Readcommited isolation and the updates are SHORT and immediately commited, no waiting - then this will slow you down a little, but not be dramatic. Consider using snapshot isolation, but for any real big workload that would require a ram disc or SSD For the tempdb database.

Comment: Yeah, but in this senario im not using the database anymore, just the static List<ScoreResult> that was loaded from the database. but i guess i could set up some locks, and just use them just before the actual "insert". Regarding MSSQL I'm considering swapping it with MongoDB, and then store the complete database on a ram disk. Maybe that would even eliminate the need of a Cashed list of ScoreResults.

Comment: Not at all. Seriously, if you consider replacing Sql Server with MongoDb because of that reason, hire a programmer that is not a beginner. Both have advantages - I would just prefer if not 90% of the "sql server is not good for me" people would know what they are doing. In your case for example you amy be better off using a simple output cache and be done with it.

Comment: You might be right, my head is just spinning trying to find the proper solution. Actually the mongoDB idea was not really aimed at the ScoreBoard output, rather the updates and the inserts to the actual database. to speed things up.

Comment: Funny given that SQL Server is a top end high performant databases in the hand of someone who knows how to use it. Yes, there are limits, but limited knowledge will also kill you on mongo db.

Comment: You're right, it would propertly just complicate things even more (for me). I think I'll stop turning my head around it. and go with my current database + the Cashed List, for drawing the score-results!.. then I'll lock the list on every Insert. and if Locking the list ever becomes a problem, I should have enough users to afford someone that could make a better system! THANKS ALOT!! you really pushed me far! comming from the idea of pulling everything from the SQL on every request!